# How do I enable indentation in an inferior scheme?

Tags: indentation, scheme, inferior-buffer

There doesn't seem to be any indentation in the default inferior scheme. At least, when I do `M-x run-scheme` the resulting repl doesn't indent my code at all.

How can I change this? Preferably without anything like geiser or other wrappers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that `RET` is probably mapped to `comint-send-input`, which doesn't do any indentation.

What I do is map `C-j` to `newline-and-indent` and leave `RET` mapped to `comint-send-input`. So I press `C-j` to enter a newline, and indent the new line, or `RET` to actually send the form for evaluation. (Actually I map `C-j` to `paredit-newline`, but `newline-and-indent` should work if you're not using Paredit).

Of course, you could reverse those and use `RET` for `newline-and-indent` with `C-j` for `comint-send-input`.

As an example of mapping one of these keys, this will map `C-j` to `newline-and-indent`:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'cmuscheme
  (define-key inferior-scheme-mode-map (kbd "C-j") #'newline-and-indent))
```

(`cmuscheme` is, for historical reasons, the name of the package that implements `inferior-scheme-mode`, i.e. the Scheme REPL.)

**Edit:**

Here's something that seems to work, though I haven't tested it extensively:

```
(defun comint-send-input-indent ()
  (interactive)
  (comint-send-input)
  (unless (save-excursion (forward-char -1)
                          (eq (field-at-pos (point)) 'output))
    (indent-for-tab-command)))

(with-eval-after-load 'cmuscheme
  (define-key inferior-scheme-mode-map (kbd "RET") #'comint-send-input-indent))
```

The idea is to call `comint-send-input`, then check if point (the cursor) is immediately before the prompt. If it's not (because `comint-send-input` just entered a newline), call `indent-for-tab-command`, which indents the line appropriately.

**Another edit:**

On second thought, I think this definition probably makes more sense:

```
(defun comint-send-input-indent ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((parens (or (car (syntax-ppss)) 0)))
    (if (zerop parens)
        (comint-send-input)
      (newline-and-indent))))
```

See `C-h f syntax-ppss RET` (and, better, `C-h f parse-partial-sexp RET`) for more information. The short version is that they can tell us how deep the paren nesting is at point, so we can use that to decide whether to `newline-and-indent` or `comint-send-input`.

Comment: I could imagine a way to write a single command Doing The Right Thing™.  Basically, the difference between a form that can be sent to the subprocess and a form that requires indentation of the rest is that the former is complete (read: balanced) while the latter is not.

Comment: Sorry but I'm really new to emacs. How can I map these keys?

Comment: @Darklightus, my bad, I've edited the answer to include an example. If you want to remap `RET` instead, just replace `"C-j"` with `"RET"`

Comment: @wasamasa, that indeed seems like it should be possible. In fact, in the Emacs 25 pretest I'm using (I didn't try other versions) `comint-send-input`  already enters a newline (rather than sending the input), but doesn't indent the new line, if the form is incomplete. However, after a quick read of the source it's not clear to me how that works. Hm, I'll have to look at it more later.

Comment: If `RET` does `comint-send-input` by default, but I just want indentation in addition to that, couldn't I do both `newline-and-indent` and `comint-send-input`? Then instead of using two keys I could use just one. How would I do that? I'd use `begin` in other lisps but that doesn't seem to do anything (other than breaking emacs) Apart from that the solution works fine by the way.

Comment: In Emacs Lisp (and Common Lisp), `progn` is the equivalent to Scheme's `begin`. However, defining a function with `(progn (newline-and-indent) (comint-send-input))` doesn't work; you want to do one *or* the other, not one *then* the other. The hard part is figuring out when to do which. (Also, function bodies are an implicit `progn`, just like in Scheme, so you probably wouldn't really use `progn` in this specific case, since the forms would be in a function)

Comment: I've now [asked about this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2016-03/msg00075.html) on the Emacs help mailing list and will update my answer with any relevant info.

Comment: I don't really see why not do one and then the other. We're already doing `comint-send-input` and now we want to `newline-and-indent` before that.

Comment: I tried defining it as `(progn (newline-and-indent) (comint-send-input)` but that breaks `M-x run-scheme` for some weird reason.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/johnmastro/c8bf5013b4e47cdd3ea0) is how you would do it. However, unless I'm missing something, I still don't believe it will give you the functionality you want.

Comment: @jbm yeah you're right, the newline put there by `comint-send-input` ruins the effect. Now I get a nicely indented next line followed by a non-indented new line. I guess I'll just wait for an answer from the mailing list. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I've now modified it a bit by removing the newlines between `comint-send-input` and `newline-and-indent`. It's now almost perfect: the only problem is when actually getting a result back it prints it after the input without a newline, like `(+ 2 3)5` instead of a newline before 5. I can't see how I could fix this, so let's hope someone sends a nice answer on the mailing list. Before I forget about this (in case nothing happens) I'll accept your answer, but please keep me updated in case anything happens.

Comment: @Darklightus, I edited the answer with a new incantation that seems to work. I'll edit further with anything I learn from the list. Thanks!

Comment: @jbm the last one seems to work exactly as I wanted. I haven't used it intensively yet of course, but it seems to work perfectly so far. Thank you very much!